# Should I bake model in Blender before importing it into Unity?

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, blender

As in the title, when is it important to bake texture for the (Blender) model to use it in a mobile game and what are the benefits from baking for performance ? Is there any problem if I didn't bake it and I use the texture directly on my model in my game ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is baking in Unity and baking in blender. Your question seems to be about baking in blender before importing model into Unity and this answer will cover that.

> how to benefit from baking for performance ?

Baking model in blender  before importing it into Unity  has nothing to do with performance. See below for why and when you should bake your model.

> is there any problem if i didn't bake it and i use the texture
>   directly to my model in my game ?

It depends. If you have a model in blender with just one basic or simple material and a texture then you do not need to bake your model.

If you have a model in blender with advanced materials or material networks then you must bake the model before importing into Unity. Material network is when you have material that is connected to many nodes to form a procedural texture. Below is an example of a material network in Blender:

[image]

There is no way to import that material in Unity.If you try, it won't look like the-same thing it would when rendered in Blender. This is why you bake the texture. When you bake it, everything in that material will be converted or flattened to an image/texture. That texture is what you can use in Unity to make it look like what it would have looked liked in Blender.

Also, baking is used to generate other specials maps like Occlusion, Normal, Alpha and Emission maps that you need to plug to the Unity material. You can also bake your Blender light into the texture.