# How to Render a model in Blender and use it unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering, blender

I know it might be asked before but I can't find anything that would help me and I am new to Blender Okay So, I'm currently working on the project in which I have a Pizza model and I have to render it and then use it in my unity project Can somebody please help me? 
[Here Is my blender model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a86IX.jpg)

Now keep in mind that it will be use in a gaming purpose so it will be viewed in 360° So, I need to be rendered in all direction.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you want to use the model in Unity? If you want to use it as a 3d model you have to export it to fbx and then import the model to Unity3D.

Comment: This depends on the complexity of the materials used in Blender so you may need to bake it into different Texture maps. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49354445/3785314) post as I have explained that.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need Blender to render it? Just export it to .fbx or .obj, import it into unity and unity will render it for you. And you can rotate it however you like in unity.